Issue with NextAuth.js: User object is not being returned in the session
I'm developing a web application using Next.js and NextAuth.js. I have set up authentication using the credentials provider (email and password) and JWT for sessions. Although the authentication seems to work correctly, I'm not receiving the user object in the session. Even though the jwt callback seems to be working and the tokens contain the correct information, the session callback does not seem to be returning the user object.
Configuration
route.js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@next-auth/mongodb-adapter";
import clientPromise from "@/libs/mongodb";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { dateNowUnix } from "@/utils/dates";

export const authOptions = {
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
  session: { jwt: true },
  events: {
    signIn: async (ctx) => {
      const { user, isNewUser } = ctx;
      try {
        if (isNewUser) {
          user.roles = ["usuario"];
          user.createdAt = dateNowUnix();
          user.updatedAt = dateNowUnix();
          user.lastLogin = dateNowUnix();
        } else {
          user.lastLogin = dateNowUnix();
        }
        console.log(`${user.email} logged in`);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error updating user ${user.email} in signIn event:`, error);
      }
    },
  },
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "email" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        // Here you should validate the user against your database
        const user = {
          id: "1",
          name: "isabel",
          email: "isa@mail.com",
          password: "12345",
          roles: ["usuario"],
        };
        if (credentials.email === user.email && credentials.password === user.password) {
          return user;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
        token.roles = user.roles;
      }
      console.log("JWT callback - token:", token);
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      console.log("Session callback - token:", token);
      if (token) {
        session.user.id = token.id;
        session.user.roles = token.roles;
      }
      console.log("Session callback - session:", session);
      return session;
    },
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

signIn page
"use client";
import { signIn, useSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Form() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { data: session, status: sessionStatus } = useSession();
  const [alertMessage, setAlertMessage] = useState(""); 
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (sessionStatus === "authenticated") {
      console.log("Session:", session);
      if (session?.user?.roles.includes("usuario")) {
        router.push("/usuario");
      } else if (session?.user?.roles.includes("terapeuta")) {
        router.push("/terapeuta");
      } else if (session?.user?.roles.includes("admin")) {
        router.push("/admin");
      }
    }
  }, [sessionStatus, router, session]);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = e.target[0].value;
    const password = e.target[1].value;

    const res = await signIn('credentials', {
      email,
      password,
      redirect: false,
    });

    if (res?.error) {
      setAlertMessage("Incorrect email and/or password");
      setIsVisible(true);
    }
  };

  if (sessionStatus === "loading") {
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
        <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
      </form>
      {isVisible && <div>{alertMessage}</div>}
    </>
  );
}

What I've Tried

Verified that the callbacks are being called.

Confirmed that the environment variables are set up correctly.

Ensured that the user validation code in authorize works correctly.

Added debug logs in the jwt and session callbacks.


What I Want to Achieve
I want to ensure that after a user signs in using their email and password, the session object contains the user's details, including their roles, so that I can redirect them to the appropriate pages based on their roles.
